# Getting Block in controllers Issue

Tags: blocks

This is my config.xml content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Attin_Exportdb>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Attin_Exportdb>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <exportdb>
                <class>Attin_Exportdb_Helper</class>
            </exportdb>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <exportdb>
                <class>Attin_Exportdb_Block</class>
            </exportdb>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <attin_exportdb before="Mage_Adminhtml">Attin_Exportdb_Adminhtml</attin_exportdb>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

This is the content of my controllers:

```
<?php
class Attin_Exportdb_Adminhtml_AttributesController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action{

    public function IndexAction() {

        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock("head")->setTitle($this->__("Export Attributes"));
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('export/adminhtml_attributes');
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock("'export/adminhtml_attributes");
        $this->renderLayout(); 

    }
}
```

and this is the content of my block file:

```
<?php
class Attin_Export_Block_Adminhtml_Attributes extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container{

    public function __construct(){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('test')</script>";
    }
}
```

The problem is I didn't get any alert. So what am i doing wrong ? thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('export/adminhtml_attributes');
$this->getLayout()->getBlock("export/adminhtml_attributes");
```

the first line creates an instance of your block , the second one retrieves the block with the name `export/adminhtml_attributes` and there isn't one.
I think you need this:

```
//create an instance of the block
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('export/adminhtml_attributes');
//append the html of the block to the content.
$this->_addContent($block);
```

I don't know if this is a real life scenario, or you just simplified it for the sake of the question.
If it's a real scenario, don't use this approach.
Just use the layout files to add your block to the content:

```
<layout_hanlde_here>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="export/adminhtml_attributes" name="export.attributes" as="export.attributes" />
    </reference>
</layout_hanlde_here>
```

Comment: im getting the alert but why i getting this : Fatal error: Call to a member function setSaveParametersInSession() ?

Comment: because you block extends `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container` and it does not have a grid block associated to it. Maybe you should make it extend `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template`

Comment: one more question: if I want to add buttons,labels, forms which class should I extend ?

Comment: That's a pretty broad question. You should ask an other one explaining what are your trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 1):

```
  $this->getLayout()->createBlock('export/adminhtml_attributes');
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock("'export/adminhtml_attributes");
```

should  be

```
  $this->getLayout()->createBlock('exportdb/adminhtml_attributes');
        $this->getLayout()->getBlock('exportdb/adminhtml_attributes');
```

exportdb means block prefix .It compile like exportdb =Attin_Export_Block

Rest of adminhtml_attributes compile like  Adminhtml_Attributes

Full class when `exportdb/adminhtml_attributes` compile `Attin_Export_Block_Adminhtml_Attributes`

Comment: but now i getting this Fatal error: Call to a member function setSaveParametersInSession()